# Break recursion with Either

Tags: haskell, recursion

In my project I ended up using the following `unfold` function in several places.

```hs
unfold :: (a -> Either b a) -> a -> b
unfold f x = either id (unfold f) $ f x
```

It feels like a very general recursion pattern (simply apply a function on values of type `a` until you get a `Right b`), but I'm failing to find such a function somewhere with Hoogle.

Is it really not defined anywhere?

Comment: https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=until

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is implemented in the [extra](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.9) package as [Control.Monad.Extra.loop](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.9/docs/Control-Monad-Extra.html#v:loop).

> ```
> loop :: (a -> Either a b) -> a -> b
> ```
>
> A looping operation, where the predicate returns Left as a seed for the next loop or Right to abort the loop.
>
> ```
> loop (\x -> if x < 10 then Left $ x * 2 else Right $ show x) 1 == "16"
> ```

The extra package also provides a monadic version [`loopM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.9/docs/Control-Monad-Extra.html#v:loopM).

As a future note, in addition to searching Hoogle for a function by name, you can simply plug in a type signature and Hoogle will look for functions matching this signature. I found the above function by entering `(a -> Either a b) -> a -> b` into Hoogle [as such](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(a%20-%3E%20Either%20a%20b)%20-%3E%20a%20-%3E%20b).

Comment: I actually searched by the type signature as well. Problem was that my in my case I use the other "side" of Either to encode the breaking :D (which yields no relevant results). Thanks a lot!

Comment: A second option, that I think demonstrates a somewhat cool idea that I've used to good effect before, is [`iterateM_ :: (a -> Either b a) -> a -> Either b Void`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.3/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html#v:iterateM_), in which you think of `Either b a` as a monad that offers a short-circuiting return mechanism rather than an exception mechanism. The instantiation to `Void` ensures that a pattern match on `Left` is total (though of course the execution of the loop itself may not be!).

Comment: Yeah, I expected the solution to be somehow related to `Control.Monad.Except` (that's why I had the "result type" - `b` in the exception's position). But it seemed to be too complicated for the given problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a version with the type arguments flipped from the `extra` version, there's also [`iterateM_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.3/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html#v:iterateM_) from the [monad-loops](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops) package.

```
iterateM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> a -> m b
```

This doesn't solve your problem in one step, but it's capturing the underlying pattern of recursion more accurately.

Note that there's nothing specific to `Either` going on in there, which does make it a bit trickier to find. I found it via hoogle by name. I didn't know if it existed, but I knew that if something by that name did exist, it would solve your problem. I derived that starting from `iterate` in `base`. It repeatedly applies a function to the output from the previous step, with an initial seed value, like you wanted. But you wanted to be able to short circuit at any time, which `Either`'s monad instance does for you, so a name like `iterateM` would make more sense. Except you don't care about all the intermediate results, so `iterateM_` would be the name that makes sense.

(Also, it turns out everything that does produce the intermediate results requires a streaming system to do it. Which makes sense in retrospect, but explains why hoogle changed what packages it was showing results from entirely when I added the "_" at the end.)

Now, as far as this not actually being exactly the type you want: yes, a bit was lost when it became more generic. But that can be recovered in a bit of an interesting way.  Look back at the type of `iterateM_`, and notice that the return value is `m b`, and `b` wasn't mentioned anywhere previously in the type. This is subtle but significant information. Since there's no way a function can just make up a value of a polymorphic type it knows nothing about, it means that it can never produce such a value at all. Let's inline `Either` in the type and see what happens: `iterateM_ :: (a -> Either r a) -> a -> Either r b`. How can we safely convert `Either r b` to `r`? Well, we know we can choose anything at all for `b`, because it can't exist. And fortunately, there are tools to handle this.

`base` contains a module, `Data.Void`, that helps here. It has a type `Void` that has no constructors. You can think of it as a type-level signifier that something can't happen. And since it can't happen, there's an adapter to make things fit together on the value level as needed: `absurd :: Void -> a`. The name comes from logic, based on the idea that once the impossible happens once you're in a silly case and might as well allow anything else to happen. At an operational level, you can have values of type `Void` in Haskell because `undefined :: Void` will type-check. But `absurd` is perfectly safe regardless - it forces its argument to be evaluated. Since any time it actually is evaluated the argument must be a bottom value of some sort, this remains type-safe.

So how does this fit in with `iterateM_`? Well, things have worked out so there's an `Either r b` value that we know must be the `Left` constructor, but using `fromLeft` feels dirty. But what's interesting here is that while `r` is constrained by context, `b` is still completely polymorphic. We can choose whatever type we want for it, because we know it'll never happen. So choose `Void`, giving `either id absurd :: Either r Void -> r`

```
unfold :: (a -> Either b a) -> a -> b
unfold f x = either id absurd $ iterateM_ f x
```

Maybe that's not even an improvement on your original. Maybe it is - the recursion is captured in a combinator instead of explicit. And for what it's worth, that combinator captures a more general pattern of recursion than something specific to `Either`. But that has the cost of introducing an extra conversion step to realign the types afterwards, and that step ends up involving a new idea that wasn't necessary before. On the plus side, it makes a nice illustration for how to use the type system to communicate things clearly.

Comment: I like it as an exercise but I agree it would not help the reader.